# Importing a Javascript Function from another File in a React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry if this is too basic. I could not solve this even by referring to similar questions in stackoverflow or by examining similar code in web.

What I am trying to do is to import a javascript function from one file (sample.js)

```
// sample.js

export default function SampleFunc() {
    return (
        <h1>
            Some Text
        </h1>
    )
}
```

to my main js file (index.js)

```
import SampleFunc from "./sample.js"

// function SampleFunc() {
//  return (
//      <h1>
//          Some Text
//      </h1>
//  )
// }

function My_App() {
    return (
        <SampleFunc/>
    )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot( document.getElementById("root") ).render( < My_App /> )
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance...

Btw my index.html is;

```
<html>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

        <!-- React 18 + Babel 6 -->
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js">
        </script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js">
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="root"></div>
        
        <!-- JavaScript Code -->
        <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting? My first instinct is that you are not loading `sample.js` as a module ([more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html)). In fat, it is not being loaded anywhere in your file at all. I'd strongly suggest you use some kind of build system to build your react app instead of relying on runtime features, because that is extremely slow and unoptimised.

Comment: Well that may be, but this in fact is just a learning exercise so optimization is not my first priority if it can be done in either way. However if it can be done only via modules, I sure have to do it that way. I'll check the link you have provided. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I get nothing. However when I decomment function in index.js and comment import, I get heading text in page as expected. This is very easy to replicate as I shortened it as much as I could

Comment: I'm curious, do you know about `create-react-app`? In short its a template for a basic React setup, including webpack (bundler) and everything else needed to get started, supporting import, JSX, but also with some simple boilerplate code to get you started? If you (like me) already know this and just want a solution to your question, please ignore this comment. Otherwise, maybe this is a better approach for you to get React up and running?

Comment: Nope I learned now. That's cool. Thanks for the info. But I still wonder how we can get this work :)

Comment: @Bqardi Btw. I think Vite does some similar task with create-react-app but much faster. You may also check it out.

Comment: One tip, If I add `<script src="SampleFunc.js" type="text/babel"></script>` to index.html and discard import / export lines / keywords from both index.js and sample.js it works. But this should not be the correct way.

Comment: Haven't tried Vite, but heard of it. And, no, not the way it should be done. I think, for now, the only way is to create all the components in the same file, without import. Also, since this way of creating a React project isn't recommended for production anyway, using it for learning or to quickly set up React for testing something out, should be the purpose for it, and then it propably doesn't matter that much if we can use import or not. Could be nice though to know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this was a tough nut to crack, but I found a solution (somewhat).

**Recap**: The issue was how to import components (in other files eg. `import SampleFunc from "./sample.js"`) in a React project using CDN's, that is without the use of webpack or any other bundler.

Normally to support ES Modules natively in browsers (import/export), you would have to use `type="module"`, but since we use babel `type="text/babel"`, we can't do this.

Babel though has implemented support for this since [version 7.10.0](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone#script-tags) (although I couldn't get it to work with that version, version `7.20.0` worked for me). We just need to insert `data-type="module"` in the `<script>` tag to make imports work:

```js
...
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.20.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="index.js" type="text/babel" data-type="module"></script>
</body>
```

Now, while imports/exports work with this setup, unfortunately we can't use `JSX` in the imported components, and there doesn't seem to be an **easy** way out of this.

According to [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/babel/babel/discussions/12059), the solution is to register a service worker that handles the transformation of those imported scripts.

The `service-worker` is implemented like this:

**NOTE!** *When first rendering to the browser (and every time you make a [hard refresh](https://www.filecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers)), you'll probably get an error, something like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at...`.
This is caused by the `service-worker` reregistering and therefore is not initially available to transform the imported files. While a little annoying its as easy as just making a normal refresh to "make everything work again". I have no clue how to implement a fix for that, and likewise the person from the [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/babel/babel/discussions/12059#discussioncomment-1391120) doesn't seem to know either.*

With that said, create a new file named `service-worker.js` (next to `index.html` eg. in the root of the project)

```
// Assuming a file structure like this
root
  |- index.html
  |- index.js
  |- sample.js
  |- service-worker.js // <- create this file
```

insert this content in `service-worker.js`:

```js
// transpile JSX using babel so it can be run in the browser, you don't need to edit this
// if you do edit this file, call `await window.serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister()` in the browser to update it

self.addEventListener('install', e => e.waitUntil(getBabel()))
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => e.respondWith(handleRequest(e.request)))

async function getBabel() {
  const r = await fetch('https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.20.0/babel.min.js')
  eval(await r.text())
}

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  const r = await fetch(request)
  if (r.status === 200 & url.host === location.host && url.pathname.endsWith('.js')) {
    const jsx = await r.text()
    const js = Babel.transform(jsx, {presets: ['react']}).code
    return new Response(js, r)
  } else {
    return r
  }
}
```

Then in your `index.js` file (or with `<script>` tags in index.html, or wherever) register the service worker with this code:

```js
function onError(err) {
  console.error('Error registering service-worker:', err)
  document.getElementById('root').innerText = err.toString()
}
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {scope: '/'})
    .then(registration => {
      window.serviceWorkerRegistration = registration
      // use `await window.serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister()` to unregister the service worker
    })
    .catch(onError)
} else {
  onError('Browser does not support service workers :-(')
}
```

For clarity your `index.js` should now look something like this:

```js
import SampleFunc from "./sample.js"

function My_App() {
  return (
    <SampleFunc/>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot( document.getElementById("root") ).render( < My_App /> )


// Service worker registration

function onError(err) {
  console.error('Error registering service-worker:', err)
  document.getElementById('root').innerText = err.toString()
}
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', { scope: '/' })
    .then(registration => {
      window.serviceWorkerRegistration = registration
      // use `await window.serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister()` to unregister the service worker
    })
    .catch(onError)
} else {
  onError('Browser does not support service workers :-(')
}
```

You should now be able to create components in individual files and import them with an added support for `JSX`.

Comment: Well that was a significant effort you put in here for both searching and explaining the solution. Thanks for your time...

Comment: No problem. I was doing it just as much for myself (I really wanted to know if this was possible) :-)